# Responsive Filemanager Upload JPG Error Keep Processing

Tags: php, responsive, responsive-filemanager

I've been using Responsive File Manager on Codeigniter framework. It works fine for these past years. But finally found some error when uploading some .jpg files. When i upload it, it keeps processing... 
**Do you know why it's error and its solution ** ? Or where can i found the error log ? If i try the jpg files on photoshop and save for web, it can be uploaded.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

dialog.php - replace "//blueimp.github.io/JavaScript-Load-Image/js/load-image.all.min.js" with "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/blueimp-load-image/2.18.0/load-image.all.min.js" around line 364
Check out blog https://www.responsivefilemanager.com/support.php